# Neo4jClient - Merge within ForEach with 1000 very slow (Unique Constraint)

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

This stems off of this SO question: [Map params with Merge or build a Batch operation via the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865060/map-params-with-merge-or-build-a-batch-operation-via-the-client)

This query:

```
FOREACH (n in {set} | MERGE (c:Label {Id : n.Id}) SET c = n)
```

Works well for being able to update or create new nodes based on a unique key (in this case, Id).  It is, however, very slow.  When I try to process a list of 42000 items, in batches of 1000, it takes about 2 minutes to complete.  In terms of hardware, this is running on my laptop (i7, 8GB RAM, Samsung 840 Pro SSD).  By the way, this is running on a clean database, so initially, there are no Matches, just creates.  (Although I want it to support updating the data, hence the use of Merge.

C# code:

```
        createUniqueConstraint(label, PK_Field); //Creating a constraint automatically creates an index
        string propKey = label + "s" ;
        string strForEach = string.Format("(n in {{{0}}} |  MERGE (c:{1} {{{2} : n.{2}}}) SET c = n)",
            propKey, label, PK_Field);
        foreach (var entities in list.Batch(1000))
        {
            var query = client
                            .Cypher
                            .ForEach(strForEach)
                            .WithParam(propKey, entities.ToList());

            query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
            Debug.WriteLine("Batch passed for " + label + " ("+entities.Count()+" items)");
        }
```

---

UPDATE

If I just manually insert each list of node types using Merge and foreach (with a unique constraint), CPU sits at 32% and it takes a long time per list of 40-50k items.
Getting the data for the 50k items takes about 2 seconds.

(I ran this with pulling data without executing the insert query and I could see the data pull took max 2 seconds)

This is the QueryText while running (it's still doing the first batch of 42k)

```
[Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery] = 
"FOREACH (n in System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Common.Models.Contact] |
 MERGE (c:Contact {ContactId : n.ContactId}) SET c = n)"
```

---

Screenshot: 
[image: 655 seconds to process 42k items]

Comment: Have you been able to isolate if it's Neo4jClient or Neo4j itself? Are you seeing high CPU or disk usage, or does the system have more capacity left that isn't being utilized at all?

Comment: I'm refactoring my code, but CPU usage sat around 20-30% and memory didn't pass 600mb.

Comment: adding some more details tot he post... if I only do inserts, no relationship merging, just straight insert with merge and unique constraint, it takes forEVER.

Comment: Looks like if I drop the batch number to 100 instead of 1000, the performance improves??  Total time using batch of 100 instead of 1000 was about 30 seconds per 42k items